# How to manage the teaser and its image field in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal and have bounced against some pretty straightforward problems. I've been seeking for a solution for a while now without noticeable success anywhere else so I'm depending on you guys...

1. **How to set a specific size to the image in a node's teaser?**
2. **Is it possible to create a teaser where appearing image is something like a cropped out center of an actual image** (I would like to have a pictures with the same size all over the teaser, while opening content could reveal actual image in original size and proportions)?
3. **How to style a teaser separately from node itself, so the content may be placed differently** (image of a teaser could appear beneath the text part while opening the node would display it above the headline and text)

I will appreciate any help and suggestions related to any of my questions here! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/[CONTENT_TYPE]/display/teaser` to manage the display for all the fields.

To configure how the image is displayed, click the gear icon on the right, choose the image style you want and click Update. (don't forget to click Save).

To view available image styles and modify them, go to `admin/config/media/image-styles`

To add a new image style, go to `admin/config/media/image-styles/add`

Hope this works... Muhammad.